# Task.Factory.StartNew() fails when two tasks are started very quickly

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

When launching two tasks concurrently (or very nearly concurrently) with   Task.Factory.StartNew(), one of them is always exiting immediately.

I have a function that is creating a task from the main thread, which then itself launches some number of tasks based on the number of parallel jobs that need to be completed. More specifically, I have an application that does a scan against 'x' number of computers remotely, and each scan job can have 'y' number of individual scan job definitions that need to run one after another. The actual scanning is done by a separate command line exe. When trying to launch against two computers, the first scan of the first computer pops up the command line window for a split second, then immediately closes, while the rest of the process continues as intended. I've tried many variations of the same code, and the only reliable fix is tossing a Thread.Sleep() inside of the foreach loop, which makes it work just fine.

The running code looks something like this:

```
private void StartClicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // Gather information about the job here

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RunJobs(listOfJobs), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)

    // Do some other stuff while tasks run.
}

private void RunJobs(Queue<Job> p_jobs)
{
    while (p_jobs.Any())
    {
        var job = p_jobs.Dequeue();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => BeginScan(job), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        // Adding Thread.Sleep(someNumber) here fixes the issue, but I don't want to rely on that.
    }
}

private void BeginScan(Job p_job)
{
    foreach(var scanPolicy in p_job.PoliciesForExecution)
    {
        PolicyScan(scanPolicy);
    }
}

private void PolicyScan(Policy p_policy)
{
    // Launch exe with some parameters here.
}
```

What is going wrong here? Why does adding a manual Thread.Sleep() fix the issue?

Comment: What type is `p_jobs`?

Comment: Also, it seems you're not really into async programming, you shouldn't be creating a task using `Task.Factory.StartNew` and then immediately waiting on it, that will tie up one thread just waiting for the other task to complete. You should instead embrace async/await properly.

Comment: p_jobs is a Queue<Job>. Also, you're correct regarding the immediate wait in this example. It has a reason in the actual code, but provides nothing in the example.

Comment: If it's not a `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, then it is not thread-safe. If you're enqueueing work into this queue from other threads, it will appear to fail randomly

Comment: The work is being enqueued before the task is created, nothing alters it (aside from the Task dequeueing in the loop) after that.

Comment: OK, then that is likely not a problem here.

Comment: As I mentioned, it is almost certainly just the speed at which the RunJobs is looping over the p_jobs and creating new tasks. A Thread.Sleep(500) fixes it 50%-ish of the time, Thread.Sleep(1000) fixes it completely. However, I know how bad the code smell is having to use a Thread.Sleep to get things working.

Comment: Are you getting an Exception or anything, either in your code or the .EXE? Because of the thread.sleep fix I assume stepping through with a dubugger wont help?

Comment: I seriously doubt there is a problem creating tasks at the maximum possible rate, there is something with your task code that isn't thread-safe. The sleep just makes the newly created task pass that area into more safe code.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]? Even one that just randomly crashes, not even guaranteed to crash every time, but it should be able to crash *sometime*? I suspect the act of creating the mcve will in fact reveal what the problem is, otherwise it will give us some clues as to what you're doing inside your tasks.

Comment: What you're describing sounds normal. If you start a task and then that task launches an .exe, the task will probably return immediately after the process has started. (You haven't shown how you're starting it.) If you don't want it to return immediately then you'd have the monitor the process you've started and not return until it has exited.